# QBittorrent not working on on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, qbittorrent

I installed QBittorent following these steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

I run it using a bittorent file. I noticed that more than half an hour ago nothing has been downloaded:

[image]

What is wrong and why does not it work ?

Comment: There would  not be  seeds...

Comment: @AshutoshKale thank you, but I do not understand your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're having, is that people aren't seeding.  You'd need to go back to where the torrent file was downloaded, and ask for a reseed.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "ask for a reseed" ?

Comment: See if you can have more people available to download from.

Comment: why there must be more people available to download it ?

Comment: More people to share the file, so you can download it.  Not more people available to download it.